# How to get data from the address bar on python?

Tags: api, python-3.x, vk

How to get data from the address bar on python?

There is the code:

```
url = 'http://api.vkontakte.ru/oauth/authorize?client_id={id}&scope=friends&redirect_uri=' \
      'http://api.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&response_type=token'
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

When you run the browser opens to allow the application access to information about friends (or the login form) when we allow, then get a link in the browser like this:

```
http://api.vk.com/blank.html#access_token={token}&expires_in={exp}&user_id={id}
```

Well, how to pass {token}, {exp}, {id} in the program?

Sorry, for my bad english :)

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the HTTP response header? It might give you the actual response url. I'm not sure if it will be foolproof if  redirects occur tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Try with this: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex51.html